# restoring windows phone 8 app after minimizing

Tags: windows-phone-8

i have developed a windows phone 8 app, everything is working fine except one.

when i minimize the app and press back it restores everything and starts from the same page.
but, if instead of using back i press app icon it starts from the very beginning.

i have tried editing app.xaml.cs but i'm not very familiar with windows development so i undid everything.

i refered this link : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx

how can i fix it? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any App will do this as long as you didn't support Fast App Resume.

To read more about Fast App Resume
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx

You can check this sample (Fast App Resume Sample)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Fast-app-resume-backstack-f16baaa6

It is not a difficult thing , just follow the steps , tell me if you have any problem

Comment: thanks a lot brother.. i need to ask one more thing..                   i have 5 horizontal listboxes with images and text in them..           the text is shown in textblock inside stackpanel(background as grey).. now if i change the background to black and opacity to 0.3, i start getting outofmemory.. what could be wrong??

Comment: Could you post it as a different question and put the code you wrote and the exception so as I could help you

Comment: here's the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327055/outofmemory-on-changing-opacity-of-grid