# outofmemory on changing opacity of grid

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have 5 horizontal listboxes with images and text in them.. the text is shown in textblock inside stackpanel(background as grey).. now if i change the background to black and opacity to 0.3, I start getting outofmemory.. what could be wrong?? here's my listbox :

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="0,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
<ListBox Name="firstList" Height="200" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Tap="firstList_SelectionChanged_1" >
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <toolkit:GestureListener DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted"></toolkit:GestureListener>
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0 " />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="200" Width="150" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
    <Image Source="{Binding image}" Margin="0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="140" Width="119"></Image>
    <Grid Margin="0,-335,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Height="30">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding brandName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FFAA1F17" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="70,-240,-10,0" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent">
    <!--<TextBlock Text="Discount" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Margin="15,0,5,0"/>-->
        <Image Source="{Binding imageSource}"  Width="50" Height="50" ></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding discountPercentage}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="White" FontSize="15" />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="150" Margin="0,-35,0,0" Background="Transparent">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="55" Background="#FF9B9A9A">
         <!--<TextBlock Text="Rs" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Margin="30,0,5,0"/>-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding productName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#99FFFFFF" FontSize="15" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have tried this and got outofmemoryerror:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="200" Width="150" Background="Transparent">
<!--Replace rectangle with image-->
<Image Source="{Binding image}" Margin="0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="140" Width="119"></Image>
<Grid Margin="0,-335,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Height="30">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding brandName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FFAA1F17" />
</Grid>
<Grid Margin="70,-240,-10,0" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent">
    <!--<TextBlock Text="Discount" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Margin="15,0,5,0"/>-->
    <Image Source="{Binding imageSource}"  Width="50" Height="50" ></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding discountPercentage}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="White" FontSize="15" />
</Grid>
<StackPanel Width="150" Margin="0,-35,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Black" Opacity="0.3">

<TextBlock Text="{Binding productName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#99FFFFFF" FontSize="15" />

</StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You code behind will be very helpful to help diagnose your OOM exception

Comment: Could you post the Code behind of this XAML , also what it toolkit refer to ? Are you using Windows Phone Toolkit or what ?

Also Please tell us what is the message that comes with the exception
Also , when I run this code without code behind , it didn't give any exception

Comment: hey i resolved it by replacing grid/stackpanel with a textblock on transparent image. thanks..

Comment: need another help are u dere??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396996/is-there-any-limit-for-items-in-a-listbox-for-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self resolved. By replacing grid/stackpanel with a textblock on transparent image.