# is there any limit for items in a listbox for windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

i have a listbox with around 150 items in it. the problem is that it is not taking any events. other listboxes have less than 90 items and they are working fine.

is there any limit or something which is preventing event handeling??

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="0,421,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox Name="thirdList" Tap="firstList_SelectionChanged_1" Height="170" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >

                            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                                <toolkit:GestureListener DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted"></toolkit:GestureListener>
                            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 0 0 " />
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="170" Width="150" Background="Transparent">
                                        <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                                        <Image Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="140" Width="119"></Image>
                                        <Grid Margin="0,-335,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Height="30">
                                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding brandName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FFAA1F17" />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <StackPanel Width="165" Margin="0,-65,0,0" Background="Transparent">
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="55" Background="#FF9B9A9A">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding productName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" />
                                                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding price}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#99FFFFFF" FontSize="15" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your code's problem but I had used Listbox with more than 500 items.

Comment: i tried reducing items to less than 100 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

vjamit please consider using [LongListSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/jj735577%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for Windows Phone 8 applications and not the old ListBox.

I have tested LLS with more than 5k items and it loads and plays just fine.

Also there is no need at all to wrap LLS in a ScrollViewer. Check below example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LLSTemplate">
        <Grid Tap="firstList_SelectionChanged_1">
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted"></toolkit:GestureListener>
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="170" Width="150" Background="Transparent">
                <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                <Image Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="140" Width="119"></Image>
                <Grid Margin="0,-335,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Height="30">
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding brandName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FFAA1F17" />
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel Width="165" Margin="0,-65,0,0" Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="55" Background="#FF9B9A9A">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding productName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" />
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding price}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#99FFFFFF" FontSize="15" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="thirdList" Height="170" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LLSTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Let me know if the above works.

**EDITED**:

Try applying the following changes on the ScrollViewer: `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`. Tested with 500+ and it works. Seems like a "bug".

Comment: the thing is, i need horizontal scrolling list. as far as i know and have searched, its not possible with LongListSelector. i possible please let me know.

Comment: Please check the edits I made..it should work - it does for me!

Comment: tried that.. still not working.. it works like this :                 when the page loads it shows 5 items and tap event works, then more data is loaded. once all data is populated neither the tap event handler is invoked nor the GestureListener.                       may be something to do with updating listbox.

Comment: but all other listboxes are following the same and working fine.

Comment: On my example I load the List Items into an observablecollection and then i explicitly bind listbox's itemsource to that collection.. tried with 500+ and that line looked like it affected it.